# Can I use Navigate Compose whilst still Compiling for a Minimum SDK of 21?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having some trouble getting my app to compile whilst using Navigate-Compose, is it currently possible to produce apps for an SDK this low, or should I increase my minimum SDK?

Comment: The `minSdkVersion` of `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09` is 21. So, Navigation for Compose is not forcing you to raise your app's `minSdkVersion` to a value higher than 21.

Comment: What makes you think a higher version is required? Post the error here so we can confirm if the error is actually because of the version being set to 21 or that it is even related to navigation.

Comment: @MARSK I think the error was slightly unrelated, some changes I made to the dependency folder caused code that was previously fine to break, as a newb to android development I assumed it could be to do with the change in compile SDK! I just wanted to know if it was worth continuing trying.

Comment: I myself use navigation compose, and I have `minSdk` set to 21. If navigation required a higher version, **it would have been mentioned in the docs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `compileSdk` version to `31` in your `gradle.build` file, such has this:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31
    
    defaultConfig {
    .....
```

Note that this won't affect the target minimum SDK version, that can still be as low as 21, it is just the version it will be compiled with.